# Why doesn't my python selenium message sender click on the first element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, instagram, message

This is a python selenium based code which sends mass DM to specified instagram users.

I would expect that this code clicks on the very first element that appears after the search. After clicking, it should write the specified message and continue this process untill all users of the list are finished.

The problem is that the code doesn't click on the user's result that appears after the search, even if the users exists. It says: "user not found". One reason for this error could be a change in the instagram Xpath which is used by selenium to locate the clickable area.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager as CM
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from random import randint, uniform
from time import time, sleep
import logging
import sqlite3

DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT = 1


class InstaDM(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password, headless=True, instapy_workspace=None, profileDir=None):
        self.selectors = {
            "accept_cookies": "//button[text()='Accept']",
            "home_to_login_button": "//button[text()='Log in']",
            "username_field": "username",
            "password_field": "password",
            "button_login": "//button/*[text()='Log in']",
            "login_check": "//*[@aria-label='Home'] | //button[text()='Save Info'] | //button[text()='Not Now']",
            "search_user": "queryBox",
            "select_user": '//div[text()="{}"]',
            "name": "((//div[@aria-labelledby]/div/span//img[@data-testid='user-avatar'])[1]//..//..//..//div[2]/div[2]/div)[1]",
            "next_button": "//button/*[text()='Next']",
            "textarea": "//textarea[@placeholder]",
            "send": "//button[text()='Send']"
        }

        # Selenium config
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        if profileDir:
            options.add_argument("user-data-dir=profiles/" + profileDir)

        if headless:
            options.add_argument("--headless")

        mobile_emulation = {
            "userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10.0; iPhone Xs Max Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Mobile Safari/535.19'
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
        options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            executable_path=CM().install(), options=options)
        self.driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        self.driver.set_window_size(414, 936)

        # Instapy init DB
        self.instapy_workspace = instapy_workspace
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None
        if self.instapy_workspace is not None:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(
                self.instapy_workspace + "InstaPy/db/instapy.db")
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

            cursor = self.conn.execute("""
                SELECT count(*)
                FROM sqlite_master
                WHERE type='table'
                AND name='message';
            """)
            count = cursor.fetchone()[0]

            if count == 0:
                self.conn.execute("""
                    CREATE TABLE "message" (
                        "username"    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                        "message"    TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
                        "sent_message_at"    TIMESTAMP
                    );
                """)

        try:
            self.login(username, password)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            print(str(e))

    def login(self, username, password):
        # homepage
        self.driver.get('https://instagram.com/login')
        self.__random_sleep__(3, 5)

        # login
        logging.info(f'Login with {username}')
        self.__scrolldown__()
        if not self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['username_field'], 'name', 10):
            print('Login Failed: username field not visible')
        else:
            self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, self.selectors['username_field']).send_keys(username)
            self.driver.find_element(By.NAME, self.selectors['password_field']).send_keys(password)
            self.__get_element__(
                self.selectors['button_login'], 'xpath').click()
            self.__random_sleep__()
            if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['login_check'], 'xpath', 10):
                print('Login Successful')
            else:
                print('Login Failed: Incorrect credentials')

    def createCustomGreeting(self, greeting):
        # Get username and add custom greeting
        if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['name'], "xpath", 10):
            user_name = self.__get_element__(
                self.selectors['name'], "xpath").text
            if user_name:
                greeting = greeting + " " + user_name + ", \n\n"
        else:
            greeting = greeting + ", \n\n"
        return greeting

    def typeMessage(self, user, message):
        # Go to page and type message
        if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['next_button'], "xpath"):
            self.__get_element__(
                self.selectors['next_button'], "xpath").click()
            self.__random_sleep__()

        if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['textarea'], "xpath"):
            self.__type_slow__(self.selectors['textarea'], "xpath", message)
            self.__random_sleep__()

        if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['send'], "xpath"):
            self.__get_element__(self.selectors['send'], "xpath").click()
            self.__random_sleep__(3, 5)
            print('Message sent successfully')

    def sendMessage(self, user, message, greeting=None):
        logging.info(f'Send message to {user}')
        print(f'Send message to {user}')
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/direct/new/')
        self.__random_sleep__(2, 4)

        try:
            self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['search_user'], "name")
            self.__type_slow__(self.selectors['search_user'], "name", user)
            self.__random_sleep__(1, 2)

            if greeting != None:
                greeting = self.createCustomGreeting(greeting)

            # Select user from list
            elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]').find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
            if elements and len(elements) > 0:
                elements.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
                self.__random_sleep__()

            # In case user has changed his username or has a private account
            else:
                print(f'User {user} not found! Skipping.')
                return False

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False

    def sendGroupMessage(self, users, message):
        logging.info(f'Send group message to {users}')
        print(f'Send group message to {users}')
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/direct/new/?hl=en')
        self.__random_sleep__(5, 7)

        try:
            usersAndMessages = []
            for user in users:
                if self.conn is not None:
                    usersAndMessages.append((user, message))

                self.__wait_for_element__(
                    self.selectors['search_user'], "name")
                self.__type_slow__(self.selectors['search_user'], "name", user)
                self.__random_sleep__()

                # Select user from list
                elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]')
                if elements and len(elements) > 0:
                    elements.find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()
                    self.__random_sleep__()
                else:
                    print(f'User {user} not found! Skipping.')

            self.typeMessage(user, message)

            if self.conn is not None:
                self.cursor.executemany("""
                    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO message (username, message) VALUES(?, ?)
                """, usersAndMessages)
                self.conn.commit()
            self.__random_sleep__(50, 60)

            return True

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False

    def sendGroupIDMessage(self, chatID, message):
        logging.info(f'Send group message to {chatID}')
        print(f'Send group message to {chatID}')
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/direct/inbox/')
        self.__random_sleep__(5, 7)

        # Definitely a better way to do this:
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB*2 + Keys.ENTER).perform()
        actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB*4 + Keys.ENTER).perform()

        if self.__wait_for_element__(f"//a[@href='/direct/t/{chatID}']", 'xpath', 10):
            self.__get_element__(
                f"//a[@href='/direct/t/{chatID}']", 'xpath').click()
            self.__random_sleep__(3, 5)

        try:
            usersAndMessages = [chatID]

            if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['textarea'], "xpath"):
                self.__type_slow__(
                    self.selectors['textarea'], "xpath", message)
                self.__random_sleep__()

            if self.__wait_for_element__(self.selectors['send'], "xpath"):
                self.__get_element__(self.selectors['send'], "xpath").click()
                self.__random_sleep__(3, 5)
                print('Message sent successfully')

            if self.conn is not None:
                self.cursor.executemany("""
                    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO message (username, message) VALUES(?, ?)
                """, usersAndMessages)
                self.conn.commit()
            self.__random_sleep__(50, 60)

            return True

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            return False

    def __get_element__(self, element_tag, locator):
        """Wait for element and then return when it is available"""
        try:
            locator = locator.upper()
            dr = self.driver
            if locator == 'ID' and self.is_element_present(By.ID, element_tag):
                return WebDriverWait(dr, 15).until(lambda d: dr.find_element(By.ID, element_tag))
            elif locator == 'NAME' and self.is_element_present(By.NAME, element_tag):
                return WebDriverWait(dr, 15).until(lambda d: dr.find_element(By.NAME, element_tag))
            elif locator == 'XPATH' and self.is_element_present(By.XPATH, element_tag):
                return WebDriverWait(dr, 15).until(lambda d: dr.find_element(By.XPATH, element_tag))
            elif locator == 'CSS' and self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTOR, element_tag):
                return WebDriverWait(dr, 15).until(lambda d: dr.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, element_tag))
            else:
                logging.info(f"Error: Incorrect locator = {locator}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
        logging.info(f"Element not found with {locator} : {element_tag}")
        return None

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        """Check if an element is present"""
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return False
        return True

    def __wait_for_element__(self, element_tag, locator, timeout=30):
        """Wait till element present. Max 30 seconds"""
        result = False
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(0)
        locator = locator.upper()
        for i in range(timeout):
            initTime = time()
            try:
                if locator == 'ID' and self.is_element_present(By.ID, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                elif locator == 'NAME' and self.is_element_present(By.NAME, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                elif locator == 'XPATH' and self.is_element_present(By.XPATH, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                elif locator == 'CSS' and self.is_element_present(By.CSS_SELECTORS, element_tag):
                    result = True
                    break
                else:
                    logging.info(f"Error: Incorrect locator = {locator}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(e)
                print(f"Exception when __wait_for_element__ : {e}")

            sleep(1 - (time() - initTime))
        else:
            print(
                f"Timed out. Element not found with {locator} : {element_tag}")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(DEFAULT_IMPLICIT_WAIT)
        return result

    def __type_slow__(self, element_tag, locator, input_text=''):
        """Type the given input text"""
        try:
            self.__wait_for_element__(element_tag, locator, 5)
            element = self.__get_element__(element_tag, locator)
            actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
            actions.click(element).perform()
            for s in input_text:
                element.send_keys(s)
                sleep(uniform(0.005, 0.02))

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            print(f'Exception when __typeSlow__ : {e}')

    def __random_sleep__(self, minimum=2, maximum=7):
        t = randint(minimum, maximum)
        logging.info(f'Wait {t} seconds')
        sleep(t)

    def __scrolldown__(self):
        self.driver.execute_script(
            "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    def teardown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
```